# How to use wordpress + django to build a website

Tags: django, wordpress, integration

I have a wordpress website ,and i want to add more functionality with django framework.Is it posible to build a hybrid website with Wordpress and Django..???

Answer (score 4):

Let’s start with the configuration. The first thing is that you need to install WP REST API v1 plugin inside your WordPress site and enable it.

Then you need to install Django WordPress Api library inside your django application

pip install django-wordpress-api
After that, add wordpress_api inside the installed apps

INSTALLED_APPS += ('wordpress_api',)
Also, if you are using DWA Views (explained later) you need to add the wordpress_api urls in your application urls

url(r'^blog/', include('wordpress_api.urls')),
Finally, you need to set up the DWA required settings; WP_URL and BLOG_POSTS_PER_PAGE.

WP_URL = https://your-wordpress-app.com/
BLOG_POSTS_PER_PAGE = number-of-blogs-to-display-per-page
and that’s it.

You can follow [this](https://swapps.com/blog/simple-django-wordpress-integration-with-django-wordpress-api-library/) link

Comment: this is awsome! Thank you for your interesting answer.